# PHP method not returning MySQL identity

Tags: php, android, json

I Want when register to Get the ID that the USER got (AUTO_INCREAMENT) and parse it in android to use it in next Activity, When I register the Value of success gives 1 and it works but thee value of ID returns value '{}'.

```
public function createNewRegisterUser($username, $password, $email){        
$query = "insert into users (username, password, email) values ('$username', '$password', '$email')"; 
    $inserted = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);
    if($inserted == 1){ 
        $json['success'] = 1;
        $json['id'] = mysqli_query($this->db->getdb(),"select id from users where username = '$username'" );    ;                       
    }else{
        $json['success'] = 0;
        $json['id'] = ""    ;
    }
    mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
    return $json;
}
```

Comment: I would created a stored procedure to create your user and return last_insert_id() or an error code... and use a prepared statement to call it and not build up queries using string interpolation.

Comment: Can you Please post the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this as untested code (I haven't used the MySQLi procedural stuff in ages... consider using PDO if you can):

```
public function createNewRegisterUser($username, $password, $email){
   $dbh = $this->db->getDb(); // assuming this returns a handle?
   $sth = mysqli_prepare($dbh, 'insert into users (username, password, email) values (?, ?, ?)');
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth, 'sss', $username, $password, $email);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);
   $errNo = mysqli_stmt_errno($sth);
   $userId = mysqli_insert_id ($dbh);
   if($errNo !== 0) { 
        $json['success'] = 1;
        $json['id'] = $userId;
    }else{
        $json['success'] = 0;
        $json['id'] = ""    ;
    }
    mysqli_close($dbh);
    return $json;
}
```

I forgot the format parameter...

Comment: But the part of Inserting data is working with me the only issue is getting the ID.

Comment: I made some minor tweaks to my answer.  mysqli_insert_id should return the identity.